# Display Html data which we are getting from server in TextView

Tags: android

Hi I am getting `HTML` data from I need to display it in `textView` with formatted  form

data which I am getting is

```
"\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;\u0026lt;b\u0026gt;Bounty Quilted Napkins, 200-Count:\u0026lt;/b\u0026gt;\u0026lt;/p\u0026gt;\u0026lt;ul\u0026gt;\u0026lt;li\u0026gt;Thick quilts to help keep your lap confidently clean\u0026lt;/li\u0026gt;\u0026lt;li\u0026gt;Soft feel to gently clean a child\u0027s face\u0026lt;/li\u0026gt;\u0026lt;li\u0026gt;Deep texture to help clean the mess\u0026lt;/li\u0026gt;\u0026lt;li\u0026gt;2009 ChefsBest Award for Performance\u0026lt;/li\u0026gt;\u0026lt;li\u0026gt;Good Housekeeping Seal\u0026lt;/li\u0026gt;\u0026lt;li\u0026gt;Available as white napkins or a variety of prints and colors\u0026lt;/li\u0026gt;\u0026lt;/ul\u0026gt;"
```

Now current I am using  below code but it is not working

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static Spanned fromHtml(String source) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return Html.fromHtml(source, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            return Html.fromHtml(source);
        }
    }
```

Some one Please help me

Comment: That is not valid HTML. It looks like it was double-escaped. `\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;` presumably translates to `<p>`, and so on. You will need to fix that up before `Html.fromHtml()` will work.

Comment: Do u have any refrence for this